# AnyChart legend icon position

Tags: format, position, icons, legend, anychart

Is there a way to change the position of the icons in the legend? The only thing I can find is the *iconFormatter* where I can set *iconEnabled: true/false*.

I'm looking for a way to set the position of the icons, like for *{%seriesName}* or *{%seriesYSum}* in the itemsFormat. So that I can place it after the seriesName, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current version of the library (v8.7.1 December 2019) doesn't support placing legend icons after the legend item text or any other option. We will take into account this requirement for future updates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm looking forward to it.